# Pyplot crashes at interaction

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3, pyqt5

I've got a pyplot which can be refreshed using a button. This works fine. But if I try to interact with the pyplot (move, resize window, zoom, etc.) it crashes:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
```

Is what eclipse says.

Below is a running minimal example to reproduce the fault. Since im a python novice my guess is that the problem is in my code.

Sys: Win7 64, Python 3.3.5, PyQt 5.2.1, Scipy-stack 14.4.1

```
# imports
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QPushButton)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        # elements
        self.hold = QCheckBox("Hold")
        self.hold.setCheckable(True)
        self.refreshButton = QPushButton("Refresh")
        self.refreshButton.clicked.connect(self.refresh)

        # layout
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1, 10)
        layout.addWidget(self.hold, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.refreshButton, 1, 1)       
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # open window
        plt.figure()
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        # delete plot if hold is checked
        if not self.hold.isChecked():
            plt.clf()
        # random plot
        plt.plot(np.random.normal(10, .1, 100))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using plt.draw() instead of plt.show() makes no noticeable difference.

Comment: I deleted the comment.

Comment: mpl does not explicitly support pyqt5

Comment: Just tried it with pyqt4, behavior is the same

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue (https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl/issues/104). Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, because of this and other reasons I soon after switched to pyqtgraph. As I've seen you have found a workaround in the meantime.